# Structuring "then" handler for both sync/async condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am struggling to fix what I think is a very simple jQuery promise problem. In effect, I need to bypass a 'then' in certain circumstances within a promise chain when a previous promise discovers it won't fire asynchronously.

I have a chunk of code (the actual, runtime code is too long to repost here coherently - apologies/mea culpa in advance) for which the "then" portion may run code that will fire asynchronously, or will complete immediately and return - no async execution.

***This has been resolved. In digging through the code, I happened to discover a spot where a promise was not being properly resolved in the no-files condition. This has fixed the problem. Thanks for the keen eyes to @Bergi that indicated something was *really* awry.

The overarching structure of the code is in this fashion:

****Edited to correct improper call to DisableProgress**

```
function writeData(){
    EnableProgress('Starting upload')
       .then(writeRecord)
       .then(uploadFiles)
       .then(DisableProgress);
}

function uploadFiles(){
   var deferred = $.Deferred();

   if (fileUploadList.length==0){
        deferred.resolve();
   } else {
        //perform async upload
   }
   return deferred.promise();
}
```

The problem is this: when `uploadFiles` detects no files to upload (a perfectly legitimate situation), no async process occurs; the promise is resolved before it is returned, and the 'then' portion that calls 'DisableProgress' never fires. (There are actually other calls in this chain that fired but are eliminated here for clarity's sake)

I thought about putting in a brief setTimeout within the uploadFiles routine to "force" the async execution in the event there were no files to upload, but that seemed an absurd hack to me. Surely there's an obvious/better way I'm simply overlooking. I've searched Google about issues revolving around resolving a promise prior to its return, but I've not seen (or recognized?) anything on point. I think I'm at a point where I can't see the trees for the forest - I'm making it too complicated. What is my error?

Comment: "*the promise is resolved before it is returned*" - that is not a problem. "*…and the 'then' portion that calls 'DisableProgress' never fires*" - nope, there must be something else. That only happens when the promise is never fulfilled. Or are you by chance using a very outdated version of jQuery? Your `uploadFiles` code should work.

Comment: Btw, is it intentional that you are calling `DisableProgress()` before anything else, or did you mean to pass `DisableProgress` as a function to `then`?

Comment: @Bergi - Had not thought of that. Will check. I just assumed I was doing something wrong with the resolve().

Comment: @Bergi you just beat me to it.

Comment: @Bergi - The last step in the chain should be the call to DisableProgress()

Comment: @DavidW you are passing the result of calling `DisableProgress` instead of passing the function to be invoked later.

Comment: @DavidW Then use `.then(DisableProgress);`! Just like the two other callback functions, don't call them and pass their result but pass the functions themselves.

Comment: I would also mention that if you are iterating through each item and uploading it then an empty list would give you a noop and you can remove the check for no files.

Comment: I realize I have transcribed the code incorrectly. The call to DisableProgress is properly wrapped in a function, not called incorrectly as shown. Will correct.

Comment: @Bergi I have corrected the code snippet re the call to DisableProgress. Great catch. I was going to kick myself if that were the issue.

Comment: Still, this should not happen. Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Surely understand that, @Bergi, just wish it were as simple as that. Will see what I can come up with. Thanks for the assist. If nothing else, you've helped me at least there's nothing *obviously* stupid I've done.

Comment: This is solved per my last edit. @Bergi - If you want to post as an answer the idea that something else was in play - that the resolve of an unreturned promise wasn't a problem, etc, I'd be happy to mark that as the answer. I hate answering my own questions; would rather give someone else the credit!

Comment: @DavidW It's fine, answer it. I'm not sure what you mean by "unreturned promise" (or at least, how that could cause the callback not to be called)

Comment: @Bergi - Sorry - internet went down for a time and I was typing responses rapidly on a phone. Not my best day for questions or comments LOL.